# Keep HttpContext.Current.Session in WCF service to service call

Tags: c#, wcf, session

I have on WCF service (WCFSERVICE_1), which calls the second WCF service (WCFSERVICE_2).
At first call i am writting some variables in HttpContext.Current.Session of WCFSERVICE_2.
But when i am calling second time, the HttpContext.Current.Session (WCFSERVICE_2) is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the answer.
If you have same problem, please read this article.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2010/02/21/using-asp-net-sessions-from-wcf.aspx